# Mint 19 tcpd INFECTED sha1sum

Tags: malware, rkhunter, chkrootkit

When I use rkhunter it always shows two warnings and possible 4 rootkit information:

```
Checking for suspicious (large) shared memory segments   [ Warning ]
Checking for hidden files and directories                [ Warning ]
File properties checks...
    Files checked: 149
    Suspect files: 0

Rootkit checks...
    Rootkits checked : 480
    Possible rootkits: 4

Applications checks...
    All checks skipped
```

The rest is ok. Using chkrootkit i always get only one alert: tcpd INFECTED. I used:

```
sudo sha1sum /usr/sbin/tcpd
```

and the answer was:

```
9ee346a9400f52e16576db35c310a72af391e199  /usr/sbin/tcpd
```

I found out that it should be:

```
cd9cfc19df7f0e4b7f9adfa4fe8c5d74caa53d86  /usr/sbin/tcpd
```

Is it posible that my system is infected? I have Linux Mint 19 mate.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `rkhunter` and `chkrootkit` before every update and `rkhunter --propupd` and `chkrootkit --update` afterward. This is to avoid false positives. Unfortunately you have no way of knowing if you are infected with just the tools, if you don't use them in this manner.

- You have stated that the sha1sums don't match when comparing them manually, this indicates that it has most likely been tampered with or infected.
- I would backup important files and erase/zero fill and reinstall the system. Then run the checks as described. *(This **does** guarantee the infection was removed!)*
- If you can't or don't wish to do that you could just delete the infected file/files and put known clean versions in there place. *(This does **not** guarantee the infection was removed!)*